# Change SystemTray Progress Indicator Color

Tags: windows-phone-7, styling, progress-indicator

i need change color of `SystemTray.ProgressIndicator` color, how i can do it?

I tried setting `ForegroundColor` for `SystemTray`, it works for only text not Inicator. Indicator always uses PhoneAccent color.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [Jamie Rodregez this is not possible](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaimer/archive/2011/06/04/system-tray-progress-indicator.aspx). Could you use the normal [ProgressBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.progressbar%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) or [PerformanceProgressBar](http://www.jeff.wilcox.name/2010/08/performanceprogressbar/) and style it so it was at the top of the page like the progress indicator?

Comment: It will be difficult... And microsoft recomend using this Indicator. Ok, i understood. Thanks.